# Interpolation in custom component property without brackets is not evaluated

Tags: angular

[This manual](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#property-binding-or-interpolation-) says the following:

> We often have a choice between interpolation and property binding. The
>   following binding pairs do the same thing:
>
> ```
> <p><img src="{{heroImageUrl}}"> is the <i>interpolated</i> image.</p>
> <p><img [src]="heroImageUrl"> is the <i>property bound</i> image.</p>
> ```

However, I tried the same with my custom component and I didn't have `{{heroImageUrl}}` evaluated:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'custom',
    inputs: ['heading'],
```

And used like this:

```
<custom heading="{{tasksHeading}}"...
```

but it didn't evaluate the expression and I got `'{{tasksHeading}}'` string. This worked as expected:

```
<custom [heading]="tasksHeading"...
```

Why didn't the first option with interpolated property work the way it's showed in the docs?